# What's the best way to display thousands of polygons in Openlayers?

Tags: openlayers, vector

I am trying to create an Openlayers map that will display thousands of polygons. And when the user clicks on each, I want some of the metadata to display. Working with this large of a dataset seems like it will be challenging. But I am trying to figure out if there is a standard way to go about this. At this point, I am think I should either

1. display my polygons with WMS and use getfeatureinfo
2. Display with WFS, Load with Strategy.BBOX, and use GetFeature to get meatadata.

Is there a logical way I am missing to load all of this data into a map and have a good speed. I was looking at this page and trying to figure out what they did: http://protectedplanet.net/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't like the BBOX strategy as I think it might be slow due to the amount of requests that may be generated.

I would use a combination of both things  you mentioned.

display polygons with WMS and use getfeatureinfo... then use WFS, to load outline the feature when clicked on and/or get more information from the database.

protectedplanet.net doesn't use openlayers just google maps. They are probably storing all the information in a KML/KMZ.

Comment: Great Thanks! I guess I am on the right track then. But I am wondering if protectedplanted is using KML, should I be doing that for its speed? And is that KML data being served by WFS?

Comment: I don't know for sure if it's KML, just a guess. But if it is it's not being served by WFS because WFS uses GML. The thing about using google apis and KML is that you need to have that KML on a public URL where EVERYONE can see it. If that's not a problem, then maybe you can try it. This is because google absorbs this KML into their servers and returns it back to the API. For these two reasons, I cannot use google maps API because of the sensitivity of some projects.

Comment: You can limit access to your public KML URL to only allow a user agent that presents the Google KML parser string.

Answer (score 3):

The main approach here is to separate rasterization with interaction. One approach (that I'm partially responsible for) is [UTFGrid](http://mapbox.com/developers/utfgrid/), which has been used by [NPR, etc](http://www.npr.org/news/graphics/2011/10/toxic-air/#4.00/39.00/-84.00) and is integrated into [TileMill](http://mapbox.com/tilemill/) and [Mapnik](http://mapnik.org/). It's also used by [CartoDB](http://cartodb.com/) and Google Maps uses a similar approach for Fusion Tables.

Protected planet uses raster tiles as well (for instance, this one: `http://184.73.201.235/blue/8/78/93` ) and has a live server behind it for point-based queries (for instance, [this one](http://www.protectedplanet.net/api/sites_by_point/-74.57080078125/43.70434987139837?callback=loadJson)).

Re: CaptDragon: there's no WFS or KML involved.

WMS and WFS will not give you anywhere near good enough performance for a public site. The BBOX strategy will not work if you let users zoom.

Comment: FYI: You can cache a WMS raster service which will give you tiles.

Comment: Yes, but that's not the main problem here, it's interactivity. You can't cache the way that WFS/WMS GetFeature works because they aren't designed to be cached tilewise.

Comment: I cache my CSW, WFS and WMS GetFeature, GetRecord, etc results all the time. These are just standards of format for interoperability and do not dictate where the source, whether cached or not, is stored.

Comment: A typical WFS GetFeature request is a request for a single coordinate; a cache for that request is only good for exact matches - which are rare in terms of user interaction. Alternatives like UTFGrid cache tiles of data and can optimistically fill the cache, unlike a cache for potentially millions of single coordinates. In this way the standard does dictate its cache-friendliness.

Comment: Wow- Thanks for all the help. Being that I am using OpenLayers and my map is in 4326 (which is not supported by TileMill), would you recommend CartoDB as a means to store and access my data though this?

Comment: Unfortunately CartoDB is also spherical-mercator-only.

Comment: @KyleK you need to decide what is important to you in terms of performance - display or query. In my experience display performance is more important than query as it is the speed in which your maps load that will give the perception of performance, more so than querying. If your back-end system is optimised then query performance does not need to suffer. I would advocate CaptDragon's approach in your case.

Comment: look at giscloud - their approach uses a customized vector rendering technique where they are storing auto-simplified vectors (based on visible view capabilities at the Z level) in binary within image files along with some custom compression techniques... then extracting the data on the client side with AND without flash support (canvas read/render technique). They also make use the Amazon cloud caching platform which provides them with the impressive ability to not only serve all these binary files incredibly quick but also detects real-time changes on the DB and just replace individual tiles

Comment: Quick Addition to last comment above -- for those who are interested - Simon at Vizuality provided a few hints which lead me to believe they will be integrating some of these techniques in the upcomming CartoDB v2 release this November. Also review some of their recent electoral real-time data mapping/rendering articles and source on their blog http://blog.cartodb.com