# Dynamically Plot Markers Based on Zoom Level

Tags: openlayers-2

I am new to OpenLayers.

My goal is to plot a large number (tens to hundreds of thousands) of markers on a map. For performance reasons, I would like to be able to send the boundaries of the current view to my external database, query the database for the points within those boundaries, and then construct a KML file to send back to OpenLayers to display on the map. This seems to me to be pretty similar to what is done when OpenLayers determines which tiles to display.

Can you point me to where I might start looking in order to implement this?

I would like to adopt the above approach due to performance issues I encountered while testing a similar idea with the Google Maps API - managing that many points in the browser's memory seemed to be very slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For performance reasons, I would like to be able to send the
> boundaries of the current view to my external database, query the
> database for the points within those boundaries.

The  [OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Strategy/BBOX-js.html) would fit your needs. Another OpenLayers example you can find useful is this one: [OSM + Google Maps + KML Reprojection](http://goo.gl/8LVOY)

Answer (score 0):

> For performance reasons, I would like to be able to send the boundaries of the current view to my external database, query the database for the points within those boundaries, and then construct a KML file to send back to OpenLayers to display on the map.

If users can zoom out, this will not work. See [previous discussion](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31807/whats-the-best-way-to-display-thousands-of-polygons-in-openlayers/31823#31823).